# Buildfire: Unhandled Packet Using Datastore

Tags: buildfire

I am using the **datastore** (buildfire.datastore) to save some data created on an admin panel. When I try to get that data, it floods the console with several attempts:

```
datastore.search again! total overall resend attempts 4
```

I then get a bunch of warnings regarding "unhandled packets" but the object that comes with it is the correct object I'm looking for. I get the data I am looking for, it is just slow and causes many warnings.

If I replace datastore with publicData I don't receive any warnings in console and everything is much faster.

From my understanding, I want to use **datastore** instead of **publicData** because I don't want the data I'm saving to datastore to be edited via the widget. Just wondering if I'm suppose to be seeing all of these warnings and lag with datastore.

**EDIT**:

Here is the code I am using for the datastore

```
buildfire.datastore.search({}, 'location', (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error fetching records: ', err);
  } else {
    this.setState({ locations: res });
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to call the datastore?

Comment: @attila226 please look at the edit I made to the post

Comment: You are correct in your understanding of Datastore. It can read and write from the control side but only read on the widget side. Your code looks good as well. In terms of the warnings, I've seen similar warnings in the console myself. I don't think you're doing anything wrong.